# Appengine - Upgrading from DB to NDB - Order

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

dear all

I'm upgrading one of my datastore entities from db to ndb. The order() call is a problem for me. As frontend will transfer a string such as "-created_at" or "title" for ordering. In the past, I basically put this value to query as shown below:

```
query.order("-created_at")
```

Now ndb doesn't support above syntax. Is there a recommended approach for translating order("-created_at") to order(-MyModel.created_at) ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are you looking for ? You have translated the syntax.

Comment: Hi, @TimHoffman, I'm looking for a method to translate input string "-created_at" to -MyModel.created_at. Because the input string comes from frontend, I can't translate it by myself. Currently, I'm thinking a switch-case structure but it's ugly in my mind. Thanks!

Comment: To be more precise, I'm looking for a function translate_order(query, order_str) which modify the query by impose ordering constraints specified in order_str.

Comment: switch case is better approach, it also separates database and user inputs. ( injecting user input directly in to database is non secure. )

Comment: Use a dictionary lookup.  use the expected set of inputs as the key, the result is the model property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dictionary lookup

```
sort_orders = {
   "-created_at": -MyModel.created_at,
   "some_other_order": SomeModel.some_property

}

def get_order(input):
    return sort_orders.get(input)
```

That way you only accept valid/predefined set of possible orders.

The `-` unary operator does work in the dictionary.

e.g.

```
s~lightning-catfish> -Series.updatedDate
PropertyOrder(<updatedDate>, DESCENDING)
```

I would personally make the function/method a class_method of the model, and the dictionary of valid orders defined at the class level as well.   That way all the definitions are in the same place.